# How to find sector key by using BDP in bloomberg?

Tags: bloomberg

Can somebody help me how to get sector key from Bloomberg using BDP.I am getting value if i use BDP("cusip Corp","cpn") is there a way I have cusip and how to get sector key like "corp" in the given example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question isn't exactly clear. If you want to get the sector of the security and you have its CUSIP, you can do this:

```
=BDP("459200101 CUSIP","INDUSTRY_SECTOR")
```

or

```
=BDP("459200101 CUSIP","GICS_SECTOR_NAME")
```

Depending on whether you want the industry sector or the GICS sector. In this example, 459200101 is IBM's CUSIP.